# How to view crash reports in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, crash-reports

One of my web pages is crashing systematically on Google Chrome 32 (Aw, Snap!).

I am trying to identify which line of code is causing the browser to crash. I've been processing by dichotomy so far, but I was thinking that there must be a crash report available somewhere in Chrome with some --possibly-- useful information.

Does anyone know how to view these crash reports (they must exist somewhere since Chrome has an option to automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google).

Note: I tried to keep Fiddler open to intercept the crash report, but I am not sure about when it's being set (I can just see that it's not being sent immediately after the crash)

Comment: I just found out about chrome://crashes, but it does not contain any report (although crash reporting is enabled). To clarify, I'm talking about a page crash landing on the "Aw, Snap!", not the Chrome process itself crashing.